# Oauth2 response from Google gives DotNetOpenAuth 400 bad request

Tags: c#, oauth, servicestack, dotnetopenauth

i am setting up OAuth2 with ServiceStack for Google. I registered google in my web.config as such:

```
 <add key="oauth.GoogleOAuth.ConsumerKey" value="key"/>
    <add key="oauth.GoogleOAuth.ConsumerSecret" value="secretkey"/>     
      <add key="oauth.GoogleOAuth.RedirectUrl" value="myurl/home"/>  
    <add key="oauth.GoogleOAuth.CallbackUrl" value="myurl.conm/auth/GoogleOAuth"/>
```

Its registered in my Apphost as such:

```
 Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[] {
            new CredentialsAuthProvider(appSettings), 
            new FacebookAuthProvider(appSettings), 
            new TwitterAuthProvider(appSettings), 
            new BasicAuthProvider(appSettings), 
            new GoogleOAuth2Provider(appSettings),
        }) { HtmlRedirect = null });
```

Now when i go to `/auth/GoogleOAuth` i get redirected to google, allow google to use my stuff, get redirected back to my own `/auth/GoogleOAuth`, where i assume ServiceStack will handle my troubles, and then i receive the following error:

```
Response Status

    Error Code
        WebException
    Message
        The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
    Stack Trace
        [Authenticate: 05/02/2015 09:30:42]: [REQUEST: {provider:GoogleOAuth,state:{thestate} }] System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)
```

I tried fiddling around with the `redirectUrl` and the `callbackUrl` but something tells me this is another problem. I build authentication with twitter and facebook fine in the same way.

The response url it crashes on is as such: `myurl/OpenAuthenticationTest/auth/GoogleOAuth?state={statenumber}&code={areallylongcode`

Any Ideas?

Edit: it seems to switch between errors:  I get this one sometimes as well:

`Unexpected OAuth authorization response received with callback and client state that does not match an expected value.`

Edit2: I tested some more and it turns out that the exact same thing happens with linkedIn, which is also `OAuth2`. ALl the `oauth1` work fine.

Comment: I changed `CustomUserSession` to `AuthUserSession` due to somewhere on the internet there was a suggestion that my session was non-existent and therefore my state was just random. But no luck.

Comment: The exception says the remote OAuth server returned a 400 Bad Request. You can [Install Glimpse and with DotNetOpenAuth](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks#setting-up-glimpse) to log and diagnose any DNOA issues.

Comment: @mythz glimpse does not log the 400 for me, only 302's and 200's show up in the history ,and the icon won't show due to the fact i don't really have a normal view.

Comment: I've only been able to debug internal DNOA issues with Glimpse myself. Can't really see what issue is here, LinkedIn/GoogleOAuth2 works w/ every app I've tried it: http://mvc.servicestack.net, http://httpbenchmarks.servicestack.net, (source code linked from [Live Demos](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/LiveDemos))[ServiceStack.AuthWeb.Tests](http://bit.ly/1ENNedP). OAuth issues are usually due to misconfigured apps but can't tell here. Proxies/ReverseProxies also mangle urls and break OAuth. Maybe test your app config in one of SS demos? [MVC demo](http://bit.ly/16CC0u0) shows debug info.

Comment: Turned out to be an issue concerning the links to and from localhost in combination with a proxy. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: Cool, can you mention what the issue was in your answer as it can help others hitting a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out be an issue in the url's i was referring to google and from google with. I had my IIS on a proxy so i could access it from the outside, however google really disliked that. When i entered `http://localhost` as my URL everything worked fine.